# Are class methods convenience methods i.e. part of the framework

Tags: objective-c

Are class methods convenience methods i.e. part of the framework e.g. +(id)alloc and instance methods are those that were implemented by the developer?

I can't seem to understand the difference between instance methods and class methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class method is a message sent to the class object, whereas an instance method is a message sent to an instance of that class.

For instance:

```
[Dog allDogs]; // class method: ask the class Dog about its instances
[theDog bark]; // instance method: tell a specific instance of Dog to bark
```

Comment: How can you ask a class something before its instantiated?

I am beginner 101 with Objective C - come from C# background...trying to learn!

Comment: You're messaging the class itself, not an instance of the class. I's equivalent to Java's static methods.